3nf vs star schema (kimball) for silver layer/curated zone
I am seeing both 3nf and star schema used for silver layer or curated zone in data warehouse. which schema should be used for silver silver layer or curated zone?
can anyone advise?

As the layers/zones in a data warehouse generally don’t have prescriptive definitions, what people put in them varies and there no one right answer
